# How do I return a borrowed Kindle book?

Tags: kindle

A friend lent me a Kindle book and we both received a notification that the loan was for 14 days.  I've finished the book early, reading it on my Kindle Paperwhite, and would like to return it to the lender, but I don't see a way to do that.  I wasn't prompted about this when I got to the end of the book and the book menu doesn't have a "return" option.  If I remove it from my device does that return it, or would that just make it unavailable to *both* of us?  (I don't want to experiment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return a loaned Kindle book:

1. Go to [Manage Your Content and Devices](https://www.amazon.com/mycd).
2. Select the Actions button
   next to the borrowed book, and then select Delete from library.
3. Click Yes to confirm the return.

[source](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_rel_topic?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200549320&ref=cssoc_FM_RE_KLN)

Comment: Oh, it didn't occur to me that I would need to go to Amazon's site to do that; I was looking for options on my Kindle itself.  Thanks.

Comment: You are right. It is not intutive to search for this option inside the website. There is also Cloud drive section you may interested to take a look : https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/apps